# foreach loop to populate multiple radio buttons from a database in a php string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, radio-button

UPDATE: 
Thanks to the answers provided by SeanWM and Styphon, I offer the full, working code to those who are looking for a similar answer:

```
<? 
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
include "connect_to_mysql.php";
$id= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['id']);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM angler3 WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
$clientCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($clientCount>0){ 

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 $anglerAvidity=$row["anglerAvidity"];
 $anglerFishMode=$row["anglerFishMode"];

 $vals = array('novice', 'occasional', 'avid');
 $radio_opts = "";
foreach ($vals as $val)
{
$checked = ($val==$anglerAvidity) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
$radio_opts .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"anglerAvidity\" value=\"{$val}\" {$checked}> {$val}\n";

}
$vals2 = array('boat', 'kayak or canoe', 'float tube', 'on ice', 'rod and reel', 'trap nets', 'other');
$radio_opts2 = "";
foreach ($vals2 as $val2)
{
$checked2 = ($val2==$anglerFishMode) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
$radio_opts2 .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"anglerFishMode\" value=\"{$val2}\"{$checked2}> {$val2}\n";
}
$content='
<h3>Please click on any buttons that are not answered. Your responses are shown below, and new or updated responses will be saved. </h3>
<hr>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="thankyouAnglerYouRevise.php?id='.$id.' " method="POST"> 
<table>
<tr ><td>I consider myself a/an:</td>
<td colspan="2" align=left>'.$radio_opts .'
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB; height: 10px;"></td></tr>
<tr ><td colspan="3" >My normal mode of fishing is:</td></tr>
<tr ><td colspan="3">'.$radio_opts2.'
</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<input class="button" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
';
require_once ('index2.html.php');
?>
```

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I am trying to write an edit page using php/mysql, and have this foreach code that works:

```
$vals = array('novice', 'occasional', 'avid');
$radio_opts = "";
foreach ($vals as $val) {
    $checked = ($val == $anglerAvidity) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $radio_opts .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"groupname\" value=\"{$val}\"{$checked}>   {$val}<br />\n";

}
```

HTML:

```
<tr ><td>I consider myself a/an:</td>
            <td colspan="2" align=left>'. $radio_opts .'
            </td></tr>
```

The radio buttons are printed and the correct value is selected.

However, I have many questions on the page, and all are called out in a string using this type of thing:

```
$title='Survey<br>';
$content='
<tr ><td>I consider myself a/an:</td>
<td colspan="2" align=left>'. $radio_opts .'
</td></tr>
```

This is all working fine, but when I try this:

```
$vals = array('novice', 'occasional', 'avid');
$radio_opts = "";
foreach ($vals as $val) {
    $checked = ($val == $anglerAvidity) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $radio_opts .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"groupname\" value=\"{$val}\"{$checked}>   {$val}<br />\n";

}
$vals2 = array('kayak or canoe', 'float tube', 'on ice', 'rod and reel', 'trap nets', 'other');
$radio_opts2 = "";
foreach ($vals2 as $val2) {
    $checked2 = ($val2 == $anglerFishMode) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $radio_opts2 .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"groupname\" value=\"{$val2}\"{$checked2}> {$val2}<br />\n";
}
```

with HTML

```
    <tr ><td>I consider myself a/an:</td>
    <td colspan="2" align=left>'.$radio_opts .'
    </td></tr>
```

and

```
    <tr ><td colspan="3" >My normal mode of fishing is:</td></tr>
    <tr ><td colspan="3">'.$radio_opts2.'
    </td></tr>
```

both radio button groups are displayed, but only the second group's radio button is populated from the db. If I switch the order around and call radio_opts2 first, then radio_opts is populated and radio_opts2 displays as an unselected radio group. That's why I think it's *almost* working if I could get the foreach to end somehow. If I end the first foreach group or call the second  foreach group within the content variable I get an unexpected T_STRING error. I knew this call was bad code, but for the sake of completeness, tried it anyway.

It's got to be some dumb thing I'm doing, not ending the first foreach loop, but when I try to use endif or break I will either get nothing echoed at all for the first radio group or throw an unexpected else error message. I have reviewed all of the manuals and spent hours searching this forum for help, but I still can't figure out how to write this code.

Thanks much for any help!

Comment: What do you mean both display but only one is populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine. You do, however, have the same `name` field for each set of radio buttons. As it stands now, both are `name="groupname"`. You should try giving the groups different names:

```
$vals = array('novice', 'occasional', 'avid');
$radio_opts = "";
foreach ($vals as $val) {
    $checked = ($val == $anglerAvidity) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $radio_opts .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"fishing_level\" value=\"{$val}\"{$checked}>   {$val}<br />\n";
    // ------------------------------------------------^

}
$vals2 = array('kayak or canoe', 'float tube', 'on ice', 'rod and reel', 'trap nets', 'other');
$radio_opts2 = "";
foreach ($vals2 as $val2) {
    $checked2 = ($val2 == $anglerFishMode) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $radio_opts2 .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"fishing_mode\" value=\"{$val2}\"{$checked2}> {$val2}<br />\n";
    // ------------------------------------------------^
}
```

Comment: Thanks, SeanWM, for this clear and excellent answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Corrected my acceptance to reflect your first response. Thanks SeanWM.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the name of groupname. For your second set of radio buttons you need to change this or the form sees them as one group of radio buttons. Change your code to:

```
$radio_opts2 .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"groupname2\" value=\"{$val2}\"{$checked2}> {$val2}<br />\n";
```

Comment: Oh good heavens. That worked perfectly, Styphon. THANKS A MILLION!

Comment: Oh my, I thought I did! So the answer on the bottom is the first answer? I have corrected my acceptance.

Comment: It depends how you sort. Just hover over the time and you can see when it was submitted.

Comment: Thanks! I did not see that. Learning much today. :)